# All I want to see are the specs

Tags: cisco

Is there a way to see the processor and speed of a Cisco UCS B230 Blade Server without the enclosure that runs it?
The enclosure that we have does not power on and all I need is to see what cpu and processor speed is in it.

Comment: Did you try looking at the CPU? Googling for five seconds aside.

Answer (score 3):

You have shown 0 effort on this.

As per Google:

- [Cisco UCS B230 M2 Blade Server | Cisco](https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/products/servers-unified-computing/ucs-b230-m2-blade-server/index.html)
- [Cisco UCS B230 M2 Blade Server **specsheet.pdf** | Cisco](https://www.cisco.com/c/dam/en/us/products/collateral/servers-unified-computing/ucs-b-series-blade-servers/b230m2_specsheet.pdf)

Comment: We don't normally favour link-only answers around here (preferring some kind of precis to accompany the link) but since this one is stapled to a cluebat, I personally intend to upvote it.